# What is the smallest positive floating point value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, numbers, double

How can I express a number in Objective-C "infinitely" close to zero but still larger. Essentially I want the smallest positive number.

I want to express the number, `.0000000000000001` in a simpler form.

What's the smallest number I can get without it being zero?

Comment: The last statement and the question don't agree - as the number, .0000000000000001, in any simpler form still isn't the smallest magnitude value (but it can be "simplified" with exponent notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use scientific notation when dealing with really small or really large numbers:

```
double reallyTiny = 1.0e-16;         // .0000000000000001
```

But the best way to start with the smallest number possible is to use:

```
double theTiniestPositive = DBL_MIN; // 2.2250738585072014e-308
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `1.0e-300` as opposed to `-200`?

Comment: It was simply an example. `DBL_MIN` is `2.2250738585072014e-308`.

Comment: Gotcha, so does it "replace" anything smaller than `2.22e-308` with that value?

Comment: Does what replace what? You can't store a value smaller than `DBL_MIN` in a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nextafter` function, as found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/nextafter.3.html). It is of the format `nextafter(x, y)` and returns the closest value to x in direction of y.

Answer (score 1):

Try the value `DBL_MIN` or `FLT_MIN`, they should be 1E-37.

Comment: @rmaddy's answer contradicts the 1e-37, is this correct?

Comment: `FLT_MIN` is roughly `1E-37`. `DBL_MIN` is much smaller.

Comment: @rmaddy The `c` style `DBL_MIN` is defined in the `float.h` and it says [here](http://code-reference.com/c/float.h/dbl_min) that it is 10 to the -37. Unfortunately I don't have my mac with me to check it

Comment: A 64-bit `double` uses `2.2250738585072014e-308` for `DBL_MIN`.